# Find and load all ResourceFunctions as top level functions?

Tags: functions, web-access, resource-management, resourcefunction

I would like to be able to use `ResourceFunction`'s as top-level symbols:

[image]

The reason being that some of them are so useful it would be really great not to have to type out `ResourceFunction["FunctionName..."]` each time.

**Is there some way to load them all into System context once?** ***For a bonus: add documentation locally.***

The first issue is that I don't know how to find them all:

[image: l]

Answer (score 8):

There is a helpful function named [PersistResourceFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PersistResourceFunction/) that permanently stores a function.

Here is what I did:

```
<< ResourceSystemClient`;
ResourceFunction["PersistResourceFunction"]["PersistResourceFunction"];
names = ResourceSystemClient`Private`publicResourceInformation["Names"]["Function"];
PersistResourceFunction /@ names;
```

Update. Here is my code to prevent scope conflicts between functions in the repository that later became reserved:

```
<<ResourceSystemClient`;
ResourceFunction["PersistResourceFunction"]["PersistResourceFunction"];
reservednames=Names[];
resourcefunctionnames=ResourceSystemClient`Private`publicResourceInformation["Names"]["Function"];
distinctresourcefunctionnames=Complement[names,Intersection[names,reservednames]];
PersistResourceFunction /@ distinctresourcefunctionsnames;
```

Answer (score 7):

I dug and found where the names for the autocomplete are cached:

```
<<ResourceSystemClient`;
names = ResourceSystemClient`Private`publicResourceInformation["Names"]["Function"];
```

If that doesn't work do this:

```
names =
  ResourceSearch[{"ResourceType" -> "Function", "Name" -> "*"}, MaxItems -> 1000][[All, "Name"]] // Normal;
```

Now you can do something like:

```
ToExpression[
 "System`" <> # & /@ names, 
 StandardForm,
 Function[
  Null,
  With[{sn = SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]]},
   SetDelayed[#, # = ResourceFunction[sn]]
   ],
  HoldAllComplete
  ]
 ]
```

And all the resource functions are dynamically loaded into the `` "System`" `` context

Comment: Looks like names has only 62 of the 447...

Comment: And wouldn't `With[{u = ToExpression[#]}, u := ResourceFunction[#]] & /@ names` be simpler...

Comment: @M.R. with all that I'm making sure a) the symbol doesn't already have an `OwnValue` and b) that `ResourceFunction` isn't evaluated multiple times. b) only covers a small bit of overhead, but it's a harmless little efficiency. As for `names` not having everything, you might need to reload the paclet? I have `485` entries in it.

Comment: That makes sense. But after running `PacletUpdate["ResourceSystemClient"]` I have `Paclet["ResourceSystemClient", "1.12.0", <> ]`, and it's only showing 69 names...

Comment: @M.R. hmm... just posted an alternate way to get `names` at least until I can figure out why that didn't work.

Comment: Is there a way to cache them like a paclet - so no redownloading occurs between kernel sessions?

Comment: @M.R. Easy enough to do with `LocalObject` or `PersistentValue`. That’s what the `"ResourceSystemClient"` appears to do with these.

Comment: Right, ok so we get this behavior for free it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
DynamicMap = ResourceFunction["DynamicMap"]
```

and now you can use

```
DynamicMap[# + 1 &, Range[100]]
```

as expected.

Comment: Right, but see the updates... how to do for all programmatically? That's the tricky part.

Comment: that is the first thing I thought of, but there might be a bug in `ResourceSearch`...

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I didn't see your edit before answering.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post how I did it by scraping, but it's not a great solution:

```
html = Import[
   "https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/all/", 
   "String"];
names = StringCases[html, 
   "<h3>" ~~ Whitespace ~~ "<a " ~~ Shortest[__] ~~ ">" ~~ 
     x : Shortest[__] ~~ "</a>" :> x];
With[{u = ToExpression[#]}, u := ResourceFunction[#]] & /@ names
```

Then we have all of them

[image]

In the system context

[image]

Then they load on demand, but trying to load all at once takes 16 minutes:

[image]

I haven't found a way to cache them and or to load the docs locally yet...